# Obj-c EXC_BAD_ECCESS error

Tags: objective-c

I'm having a strange crash, at the 4th line below.

```
{
...
int exp = [[resourceCompletionReward objectAtIndex:experienceD] integerValue];

int xx = mySprite.x;
int yy = mySprite.y;

[self setupRisingText:exp withX:xx withY:yy];
...
}

-(void)setupRisingText:(int)risingValue withX:xx withY:yy {
    ...
}
```

When it tries to run the setupRising Text method it just crashes. Can't see anything wrong though?

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: show full code of setupRisingText: also try to use breakpoint.

Comment: you were getting compile time error or runtime error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ever you do with `xx` and `yy` in `setupRisingText:::` they are treated as id (something like `NSObject *`, not exactly like that but similar)

So instead of int variables pointers to objects (any object, not just subclasses of NSObject) are accessed and dealt with. That is the default for any parameter without a type.

Use

```
-(void)setupRisingText:(int)risingValue withX:(int)xx withY:(int)yy {
    ...
}
```

instead.

BTW, if you used `NSNumber` you would have less of a problem here.

Comment: I didn't understand why no datatype will be treated as `id`? and NSNumber **Must not** be used here. NSNumber can only be used for json, coredata etc where you need them to wrap.

Comment: id is the compiler's default if no type is given. Fullstop.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering, shouldn't your method look like this?

```
-(void)setupRisingText:(int)risingValue withX:(int)xx withY:(int)yy {
    //NSLog(@"%d",risingValue+xx+yy);
}
```